# Call performSegueWithIdentifier from didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad, segue

I want to call programmatically a `segue` from the `imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:` method, but it doesn't work. It doesn't crash, but doesn't work. It just does nothing. The `prepareForSegue` method is called correctly.

```
- (void) imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker 
         didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   rutaFoto = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aGaleria" sender:self];
}
```

The `segue` links 2 `UIViewControllers`.
And if I call the segue with `performSegueWithIdentifier` from other place (e.g. from a push `UIButton` method), it works.
Any ideas?

Comment: What kind of segue is "aGaleria" ? Modal ? Push ? Try calling the segue in *viewDidDisappear*.

Comment: It's modal. I tried to call it from viewDidDisappear but it didn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion: and put the call to performSegueWithIdentifier:sender: in the completion block (dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: is depreciated anyway, so you shouldn't be using it).

```
      [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
           [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aGaleria" sender:self]; 
      }];
```

Comment: If I write this:  `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aGaleria" sender:self]];` I get this error: _Sending 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void(^)(void)'_

Comment: Oops, sorry for my syntax error. It worked! Thank you so much! My main viewController is shown for a moment, and then goes to the Galeria viewController. Is there any way to avoid the mainViewController to be shown?

Comment: Have you tried doing things in the reverse order? Do the segue first, and then dismiss the imagePickerController?

Comment: Yes, I tried, but it didn't work. If I call the segue before the _didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo_ method is finished, the segue does nothing.

Answer (score -2):

I'm wondering if this is to do with the main thread already handling a change in the current ViewController, the transition between didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo to the original ViewController from which it was triggered from.

I'd try two things, the first is to put a delay when you call the aGaleria segue:

```
sleep(2.0);
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"aGaleria" sender:self];
```

The second, and much better option, is to perform the segue from the view AFTER you have finishedPickingMediaWithInfo. You could set up a new NSNotificationCenter trigger in the original ViewController and then trigger it with a delay in the didFinishPicking method:

Comment: I tried both, they didn't work. The didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method collects the info after choosing a picture in the gallery, but the gallery controller is dismissed only when the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method finishes, so when I call the segue, the simulator still shows the gallery, not my main viewController. So that must be the problem, but I don't know how to solve it...